# How do ı move UITextFieldDelegate to ViewModel

Tags: swift, mvvm, uitextfield

```
extension ViewModel: TextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        search()
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}


protocol TextFieldDelegate: AnyObject {
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
}
```

I created the ViewModel in this way

```
searchView.textField.delegate = viewModel
```

and also I defined it this way in ViewDidLoad but I get the error that
**Cannot assign value of type 'ConsentListSelectionViewModel' to type '(any UITextFieldDelegate)?'**

Xcode offers me this as a solution

```
searchView.textField.delegate = viewModel as? any UITextFieldDelegate
```

when I run it this way, the delegate is equal to **nil** and there is no triggering.

What do I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I wouldn't recommend you doing this, because `UITextFieldDelegate` should stay on the view layer. Instead, delegate implementation details of `UITextFieldDelegate` methods to your view model.

But if you really want to, you need to declare the view model in your view the way that the view is certain that the view model implements `UITextFieldDelegate`. For instance:

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewModel: NSObject { }

extension ViewModel: UITextViewDelegate { }

class YourView {
    let viewModel: ViewModel & UITextViewDelegate
    init(viewModel: ViewModel & UITextViewDelegate) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }
}
```

Or a protocol-based approach:

```swift
import UIKit

protocol ViewModel: UITextViewDelegate { }

class DefaultViewModel: NSObject, ViewModel { }

class YourView {
    private let viewModel: ViewModel
    init(viewModel: ViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with your point not to couple the delegate to the view model. Just keep everything in the view, this will allow you to switch more easily  to other UI framework later on.